# Expected number of characters for monkey to type ABCDAE - Using generating functions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, markov-chains, generating-functions

I am interested in finding the estimated number of characters for a monkey to randomly type ABCDAE.

Keyboard in question is 26 keys (English alphabet) with independence and uniform probability.

I understand how probabilities of progressing from each state can be found from Markov chains, i.e. how typing an A at the 2nd/3rd/4th/6th position of the string will only require BCDAE to be typed subsequently.

However I am confused with how to use generating functions to find the expected characters before this is typed.

Any resources or working through this would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: How many of keys are there on the keyboard? Are the key presses independent [(experimentally not the case for real monkeys)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_monkey_theorem#Real_monkeys)?

Comment: @Henry 26 capital letters is all that can be typed (English alphabet). And  yes, the presses are independent, each key is equally likely to be typed at any point